# Jest document is not defined from source file

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme, document, jsdom

I just encountered very weird problem, that in jest document is not defined. That document (DOM) comes from other source file. I tried to use dockblock notation / comment on top on test file.

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
```

Unfortunately unsucessful.

I am gettin this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined

```
  1 | var AppSettings = {
> 2 |     mainPath: document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0].href
```

Any ideas why that could be? My jsconfig testenvironment is set to jsdom also. Nothing helps it seems...

Here is the structure of jest test:

```
const mockProps = 
{
        translate: translate,
        service: service1,
        httpService: http,
        toaster: toastr
};

    describe("Test information", () => {
        let component;
      
        beforeEach(() => {
          component = shallow(<Information {...mockProps}/>);
         });
      
        it("should render", () => {
          expect(component).toBeDefined();
        });
      
      });
```

My Information component uses mainpath variable to get data from server. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you get the element? Print it.

Comment: Still same problem.. Cannot move forward with tests...

Comment: Can you provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?